# Sockets vs .Net Remoting vs WCF for my service?

Tags: wcf, sockets, service, tcp, remoting

I need to create a service (in .Net) over a local network that will listen for requests and send sms. I'm confused about what the best solution might be:

- Sockets
- Net Remoting
- WCF

There should be a server, and multiple clients will connect and send bulk sms messages.

Can somebody advise what might be the best option?

I created this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Remoting is a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using WCF or ASP.NET Web API. See the note at the top of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xws7132e.aspx for proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should stick with WCF, unless performance is critical to you application. It has these advantages over the other technologies.

- Shorter development time than with Sockets
- WCF supports more protocols than .NET Remoting (Named pipes and MSMQ)
- Clients don't have to be .Net based whereas with .Net Remoting they will have to be .NET

So your service should be more flexible, maintainable and less costly to build with WCF.

Read this: "[From .NET Remoting to the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857.aspx)".